# How do you remove the wall spacer from Ikea Besta 141413

Tags: cabinets, storage

For the Besta IKEA cabinet I put the spacer 141413 in the wrong holes and now it won't come out.  The cabinets are pressboard and I am afraid if I try wd40 or oil it will make the sawdust puff up. Picture below.  When I try to pull the prongs out there is just no movement.  I already broke one off, by pulling too hard. The reason I need them out is because apparently the guide for the rack that the cabinets hang are supposed to go in those holes.
[image: Prongs][image: Prongs]

Comment: Try sliding a butter knife in there and twist it.

Comment: And be aware that Ikea is good with parts... depending on your location, you might even be able to do it online and have them ship to you.

Comment: @Jack I was able to get one out going **really* slowly with the knife.  But the other one broke off so know just the pegs are stuck inside.  I will go even slower with all the rest. Only 16 more to go.  :| Thanks for responding.